# Made up/made up of

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

Let's say you are trying to make the audience guess what a particular item is **made up**, like a chooey black desert. And you say:

> ''You'll never guess what this is **made up**''

Or

> ''You'll never guess what this is **made up of**''

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct phrase is

> You'll never guess what this is **made up of**

meaning you are referring to the constituents, expressing the relationship between the *parts* and the *whole*.

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about a **dessert** (not *desert*), then you'd better say *You'll never guess what it's **made out of***. We usually use *made out of* when we talk about something that has been changed or transformed from one thing into another.

***Made up of*** can be used like this:

- The Executive Committee shall be made up of a Chairperson and six members.
- The advisory team was made up of researchers and specialized social workers.
- Those courts have tribunals made up of three judges, one of whom is the president.

Comment: I nearly got your answer, BUT, the examples you have given made it a bit off(from a desert's specificity 'made out of' usage then turned into 'made up of') a conjuction was not used here that's why. Anyway, the answer is still good.

Comment: John, you have used "desert" again. How can a desert be chooey? We both are talking about food, aren't we? If we are, you should use "dessert".